# How to make applyForce() go a specific point in a scene

Tags: ios, swift, skaction

I am making a game right now, and currently I am making a custom transition. To keep it simple, in my transition each node is assigned to slide either right, left, up, or down. I would like each node to slide off the screen at the same time. Here is my code:

```
let slideAction : SKAction
var completed : Bool = false
let distance : CGFloat
let duration : NSTimeInterval = 3
//Slides the node in the direction specified
switch direction {
case .Left:
    distance = abs((child.position.x + child.frame.size.width / 2) - 0)
    slideAction = SKAction.applyForce[![enter image description here][1]][1](CGVector(dx: -distance / CGFloat(duration), dy: 0), duration: duration)
    child.runAction(slideAction, completion: {func Complete () { completed = true}})
    break
case .Right:
    distance = abs((child.position.x - child.frame.size.width / 2) - currentScene.frame.size.width)
    slideAction = SKAction.applyForce(CGVector(dx: distance / CGFloat(duration), dy: 0), duration: duration)
    child.runAction(slideAction, completion: {func Complete () { completed = true}})
    break
case .Up:
    distance = abs((child.position.y - child.frame.size.height / 2) - currentScene.frame.size.height)
    slideAction = SKAction.applyForce(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: distance / CGFloat(duration)), duration: duration)
    child.runAction(slideAction, completion: {func Complete () { completed = true}})
    break
case .Down:
    distance = abs((child.position.y + child.frame.size.height / 2) - 0)
    slideAction = SKAction.applyForce(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -distance / CGFloat(duration)), duration: duration)
    child.runAction(slideAction, completion: {func Complete () { completed = true}})
    break
default: //The default is Shrink
    break
}
```

Here is a gif for more info:

[image: I want them to all go off the screen at the same time.]

I want them to all go off the screen at the same time. Thank you, any help is appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Instead of that if somebody could tell me what the actually applyForce function does.

Comment: Have you read the docs for the function? It explains what it does there.

Comment: Could you supply link. I couldn't find one.

Comment: Google "sknode" and "applyForce". It will be the first link.

Comment: It doesn't show up. Could you please give a link.